# Rarely the fetching of message bodies results in wrong message number in the mail server, so the body of a different message is returned

Tags: jakarta-mail

I have a client app which listens for added and removed messages from some mailboxes and folders and I'm using Javamail 1.5.6.
I have a really strange issue and very difficoult to debug.

For only one mail account, which receives about 1000 messages every day, in two different days I got a body belonging to a different message from the expected one.

I asked for log files to mail server customer service and there I can see a wrong messageNumber in my FETCH BODY request, for example:

```
20191024 15:49:24 00991EA7 IMAP4 FETCH BODY msg=255264 length=3268
20191024 15:49:24 00991EA7 IMAP4 FETCH RESPONSE user 'XXX@userid.local' command 'A245 FETCH 19 (BODY.PEEK[])' Time=0
```

I was able to reconstruct the event and I'm sure that the message, before the time of body request, had messageNumber 18 and not 19.
Moreover, messages in previous positions (17, 16, 15 etc..) have been rightly retrieved, the mail server log too shows right FETCH BODY.

From the time of last IMAPFolder.open(), only one expunge has happened on a message located in a in a position prior to 19, so all messages following that position have been shifted to left of one position.

Here follows a summary of main events:

1. IMAPFolder opening
2. A new message is added in mail-box, messageNumber: 19 (it will be this one which presents a different body)
3. Other three new messages are added, so 20, 21 and 22
4. The message having messageNumber 5 is explicitely expunged, so following messages are shifted to left
5. The messages in 22, 21 and 20 are explicitely expunged
6. Finally the message, now in 18 due to last expunge, is requested to get its body and attachments, but the mail-server logged "FETCH 19" and returned different body.

Unfortunately I haven't javamail debug logs, because they are too verbose and big to retain them for too many days

Thanks

Comment: If you're operating on message numbers, are you calling Folder.getMessage(18) to get the Message object that subsequently results in "FETCH 19" requests?  I need to better understand how you're managing message numbers and Message objects.  Of course it would really help to see the debug output to understand what's going on.  You might also want to try the latest version 1.6.4 although I don't think there's any fixes there that are relevant.  What server are you using?

Comment: No I don't, no call to getMessage, firstly I start with UIDFolder.getMessageByUID, then to retrieve body and attachments I start a full parsing so I parse every part of that message.
Those FETCH are logged when I do Part.getContent.

Saying differently I'm not using messageNumber at all, I cache already parsed messages to database without storing body and attachments, so when it comes the time to get them I always start from the UID to get javax.mail.Message and then start parsing to get body and attachments
Thanks @Bill

Comment: > What server are you using? 
It's not a known server outside Italy, it is a PEC server (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certified_email) for which I don't know which product it uses under the hood

Comment: This will probably take more debugging than we can reasonably do in the comments section of a post.  Try sending me more details at javamail_ww@oracle.com.

Comment: Let me see if I understand...  Somehow you discover the UID for a message.  You then get the corresponding Message object and extract a bunch of the parts of the message, saving them in your database, along with the UID of the message they correspond to.  Sometime later you need to do additional processing of the message so you once again use UIDFolder.getMessageByUID to get the Message object corresponding to the message.  But when you try to operate on the Message object, you discover that it refers to a different underlying message.  Is that right?

Comment: I'm not sure where in your sequence of events the Folder is being closed and reopened.  Also, it's your application that's explicitly expunging messages, right?  How exactly is it doing that?

Comment: @BillShannon Messages sent to javamail_ww@oracle.com fail -> javamail_ww is not found in oracle.com.
Where can I write you? Thx

Comment: Sigh.  Looks like someone broken that email address again.  Try javamailhelp@gmail.com.

Comment: Ok, yesterday I sent you a message, really thanks for your time

Comment: I don't see a message to javamailhelp.

Comment: I have just re-sent message, from my GMail account this time, I hope you received it this time, anyway previous message resulted delivered on 03/12/2019 08:57 (Italy time)

Comment: Got your message.  Will look at it as soon as I get a chance.